# gwt beginner- where to put code that will be purely server side code eg. listener

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I understand that in a GWT application, the code is clearly demarcated into "client" "shared" and "server"

And calls to server side code are made through RPCs.

What I want to know is, if I create a new servlet in a java web app that uses GWT, and that servlet does not use GWT(i.e. regular Java servlet) then can I even create such a servlet? Also where do I put the code for such a servlet?

I want to implement a server side listener which constantly scans for new incoming items in a queue- and I want to do this portion of the web app without using GWT... Can I even implement something like this? Will this code also be in "server"- or will this code be in a different place altogether?

Answer (score 0):

You set it up like you set up any other server based code in GWT, following the same ideas as you normally use for a servlet.  In GWT you normally extend `RemoteServiceServlet` for doing RPC, but if you look at its parent classes, it extends from `HttpServlet`.  So just follow standard servlet implementations and stick the code into the "server" directories and add the servlet mappings into your web.xml.